# Deleting a Key in json but Keeping the Values, Using Python

Tags: python, json

I need to get rid of the key at the top "firstname.lastname@mail.com", is there a way I can do it without losing the data in the values?

The only solution I was able to think of is to convert the json to python dictionary, get the values, clean them up, and write them back to a json file, but I have a couple of large json files to perform this on, so the solution I came up with is kind of tedious.

```
{
"Students": [{
    "firstname.lastname@mail.com": {
        "First_Name": "studnet's first name",
        "Last_Name": "student's last name",
        "Grade": "student's grade",
        "Email": "firstname.lastname@gmail.com"
    }
}]
}
```

Desired outcome:

```
{
"Students": [{
    "First_Name": "studnet's first name",
    "Last_Name": "student's last name",
    "Grade": "student's grade",
    "Email": "firstname.lastname@gmail.com"
}]
}
```

Comment: You have found the solution. JSON isn't manipulated directly, you always parse it first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each entry in the list of students contains a dictionary with a single email key, this will work; otherwise, show a more representative example.  You really can't manipulate JSON easily without parsing.

```py
import json

original = '''{
"Students": [{
    "firstname.lastname@mail.com": {
        "First_Name": "studnet's first name",
        "Last_Name": "student's last name",
        "Grade": "student's grade",
        "Email": "student's email"
    }
}]}
'''

s = json.loads(original)
for i,student in enumerate(s['Students']):
    for k,v in student.items():
        s['Students'][i] = v
print(json.dumps(s,indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Students": [
    {
      "First_Name": "studnet's first name",
      "Last_Name": "student's last name",
      "Grade": "student's grade",
      "Email": "student's email"
    }
  ]
}
```